# HttpURLConnection Connection Timeout Issue with Paypal

Tags: java, paypal, httpurlconnection, firewall

I believe I already know the problem but I'm not 100% so I just want someone to put my mind at ease. I'm using the sample code supplied by Paypal for their Express Check but every time I run the code it makes it to the line `DataOutputStream output = new DataOutputStream( conn.getOutputStream());` but I always get a `Connection timed out: connect` obviously this isn't the most informative error message however I have found a few questions/answers that could indicate that my firewall is blocking the web address (`https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp` OR `173.0.82.83`) or it is blocking the port `443`. So all I really want to know is am I correct in thinking that this error is being caused because of a firewall issue? If so what can I do to resolve this?

Here is the part of the sample code that is making the call.

```
try {
    URL postURL = new URL( getExternalURL() );
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)postURL.openConnection();

   // Set connection parameters. We need to perform input and output,
   // so set both as true.
   conn.setDoInput (true);
   conn.setDoOutput (true);

   // Set the content type we are POSTing. We impersonate it as
   // encoded form data
   conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        conn.setRequestProperty( "User-Agent", agent );

   //conn.setRequestProperty( "Content-Type", type );
   conn.setRequestProperty( "Content-Length", String.valueOf( encodedPaypalData.length()) );
   conn.setRequestMethod("POST");

   // get the output stream to POST to.
   DataOutputStream output = new DataOutputStream( conn.getOutputStream()); // Connection Times out all the time here.
   output.writeBytes( encodedPaypalData );
   output.flush();
   output.close ();

   int rc = conn.getResponseCode();

   if (rc != -1) {
       BufferedReader is = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
       String line = null;
       while (((line = is.readLine()) != null)) {
          responseText = responseText + line;
       }
       nvp = deformatNVP(responseText);             
   }

} catch (IOException ioe) {
    ioe.printStackTrace();
}
```

Here's the error that appears in the console. I've also ran in TCP/IP monitor and I can see that the request is sent however it returns `500 internal server error`.

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.BaseSSLSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(Unknown Source)
at uk.co.cdl.webclient.servicefacade.payment.PaypalPaymentService.paypalHttpCall(PaypalPaymentService.java:174)
at uk.co.cdl.webclient.servicefacade.payment.PaypalPaymentService.registerPaypalExpressCheckoutTransaction(PaypalPaymentService.java:126)
at uk.co.cdl.webclient.model.paypal.RegisterPaypalPayment.doPost(RegisterPaypalPayment.java:35)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:225)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:999)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:565)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:309)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

**EDIT**

I have just been speaking to another developer and he has had the theory that it could possibly be our proxy that is stopping it connecting. I am now investigating this as well.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried opening this link in the browser and see what happens.I received this :

```
ACK=Failure&L_ERRORCODE0=81002&L_SHORTMESSAGE0=Unspecified%20Method&L_LONGMESSAGE0=Method%20Specified%20is%20not%20Supported&L_SEVERITYCODE0=Error
```

If you are sure it is a firewall issue,you need to ask your network admin to whitelist this address.

Otherwise,not recommended though ,try setting up an HTTP proxy to bypass the firewall.

I would also suggest using `HTTPSURLConnection` instead of the base class.

Comment: Yes I have and I do get a response similar to what you have put. I have just thought of another theory which I will update my question with.